# Split Spark syslog

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

How to split Spark's syslog after say some 100MB. Ours is a streaming application running with YARN, which produces container's syslog but it keeps mounting and sometimes reaches beyond 20GB. How to split these syslog's. Is there a parameter for the same.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **syslog** ?

Comment: Our own custom print statements which appears executor wise. In executor tab.

Comment: If it's your own print statements, you are in charge of log rotation. For example, if you use log4j, you can set a log max size to be able to split your logs evenly.